# React Native Community Picker Not showing anything and does not open

Tags: reactjs, react-native, picker, tsx

I am using react native community picker. I can't see anything in the picker or open it.

```
const Item = Picker.Item as any;
    
    function ActivityPicker() {
        const [value, setValue] = React.useState('key1');
        return (
          <View>
            <Picker
              testID="basic-picker"
              selectedValue={value}
              onValueChange={(v) => setValue(v)}>
              <Item label="hello" value="key0" />
              <Item label="world" value="key1" />
            </Picker>
          </View>
        );
    }
```

seeing also this kind of error

```
 Argument of type 'ReactText' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<string>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I'd recommend to make the picker show up is define some dimensions:

```
       <Picker
          style={{height: 50, width: 100}} // <-----

          testID="basic-picker"
          selectedValue={value}
          onValueChange={(v) => setValue(v)}>
          <Item label="hello" value="key0" />
          <Item label="world" value="key1" />
        </Picker>
```

Comment: Thank you, I also needed to add v as string in the setValue